# Cannot remove a Point Cloud from pclvisualizer in Windows, although it works in Linux

Tags: c++, qt, point-cloud-library, qvtkwidget

I am working with QT and have a QVTKWidget (pclvisualizer) `viewer` to render and show the point clouds in my program. 
I add a cloud with the ID name to my viewer which works well in Linux and Windows. But when I try to remove the point cloud from the viewer, the cloud is only removed in Linux - in Windows nothing happens and my Error message is displayed.

```
viewer->addPointCloud( myCloud, name ); // this works


if (viewer->removePointCloud(name)) { // this works only in linux
    std::cout << "SUCCESS: pointcloud was removed from the viewer! ID: " << name << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "ERROR: cannot remove cloud from the viewer! ID: " << name << std::endl;
}
```

Linux compiler is g++ 5.4.0.
Windows version is compiled using Visual Studio 2015.

I have no idea what to do to fix this error. Any ideas what to do/what the problem might be?

Comment: Do you have the same PCL version both on Linux and Windows? It might be the case that some bugs have been fixed in the newer version.

Comment: I actually run PCL 1.8.1 on Linux and PCL 1.8.0 on windows. But this would be a major bug, that must have been reported earlier.

Comment: I would suggest that you use the same version. You might have the revision where this issue has not been fixed on Windows.

Comment: That was in deed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear! Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have the revision where this issue has not been fixed on Windows. I would suggest that you use the same version of PCL on both OS.